# Information authenticity on server-side with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently having some experimenting with Facebook API before I'll start developing with it. And i came across an issue..

When there's an API request, it is done between the client side and facebook. And in case the information should be saved on the server, the client side - to my knowledge - is supposed to send the information to the server. But how does the server can know that the information indeed was received from facebook, and that it's not the client side that is trying to fabricate the information? Is there any way that the facebook API will send the information directly to the server, or send it with some signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; you cannot trust any information from the client.

Fortunately, you can use the Facebook API on any platform or language you want.

Comment: That means that the server should acquire somehow the client's token (or whatever it is, received on facebook login) to have the right permissions to validate or just pull the data on itself.. Or is there some better way to do that?

Comment: You can use OAuth through the server.